# Parsing XML Element value entirely in SQL form arbitrary string

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

We have log/audits we have compiled over some time that we would like to run some brief reports on.

One of the columns in the logs is JSON, but contains XML. We want to be able to parse out the value of a certain XML tag for each of the rows. So given an arbitrary string such as the following:

```
{ "XmlData" :"<tag1><tag2><TagToParse>234</TagToParse></tag2><tag1>".....}
```

I would like to run a sql query that return 234 when I give it the tag name **TagToParse**

What is the easiest way to do this ENTIRELY in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Give your container will always be tag1, then something like this should do it:

```
DECLARE @MyXML XML
SET @MyXML = '<tag1><tag2><TagToParse>234</TagToParse></tag2></tag1>'

SELECT
 a.b.value('(/tag1//TagToParse/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Tag
FROM @MyXML.nodes('tag1') a(b)
```

Good luck.

Comment: As I mentioned before, the string above is not entirely XML, it is JSON with an XML string inside of it, so I don't believe this will work unless I was able to parse out the XML string.